# Как правильно кэшировать запись в БД?

Tags: кэширование, memcached, mysql

Просветите про общие практики кэширования частых записей в БД?

Онлайн шутер, от каждого игрока по апдейту раз в секунду - кол-во снарядов, топлива. Их надо сохранять в БД до следующего визита. Но каждый раз выполнять SQL запрос как-то неоптимально, мне кажется.

Мысль хранить данные тех, кто сейчас онлайн в оперативнке, напр. memcached. Допустим, жизнь кэша ставить в 15 минут с последнего чтения. И считать, что если чел 10 минут не читал/писал свои данные, он отвалился, и надо их слить в БД наконец.

Вопрос: как организовать этот garbage collection, с предварительной записью в БД?

Смутно предполагаю, что надо там же в кэше держать запись с ключами всех закэшированых элементов, и отдельным процессом по расписанию пробегаться по всем, сравнивая время последнего обращения с текущим. Подтвердите, что в верном направлении продвигаюсь наощупь.

**Upd** похожая [задача с кэшированием счётчиков](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/High-concurrency-counters-without-sharding).

Comment: @sergiks 50% принятых вопросов, 

[Вопрос][1] ответ есть, но не принят, комментария нет, а вопросы поступаю от Вас.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/145986/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: @Shrek: «Зачем постоянно пинговать сервер?» это не ответ, который меня устраивает. Вопрос про узкую изолированную задачу. В архитекторы приложения не приглашают. Надеюсь, тут появятся эксперты.

Comment: построил в итоге по варианту с "каталогом закэшированного", который хранится так же в кэше. По крону запускается сборщик мусора, который сливает в БД записи старше X, и удаляет их из кэша. Такое решение работает.
Риск — только внезапного сброса кэша — пострадают достижения юзеров последних 10 минут. Все важные операции типа приобретения гаджетов сохраняются в БД сразу, без кэша.
Всем спасибо за участие!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На чем это все крутиться то? на своем движке или готовом?

Есть такая штука как "Актуальность данных", т.е. кешировать запрос на 10 минут. и потом смотрим эти результаты схожи с теми которые сейчас идут от пользователя на сервак или нет, если нет то кеш обновить данные записать.

## ##########

**Но, есть одно но**

> Онлайн шутер, от каждого игрока по
> апдейту раз в секунду - кол-во
> снарядов, топлива. Их надо сохранять в
> БД до следующего визита. Но каждый раз
> выполнять SQL запрос как-то
> неоптимально, мне кажется.

Сохранять нужно до следующего визита, визита чего? Нового запроса, или когда пользователь вновь войдет в игру?

> Но каждый раз
> выполнять SQL запрос как-то
> неоптимально, мне кажется.

А какие есть варианты, если нужно постоянно хранить в БД записи раз в секунду?

Храни их на стороне клиента в сессии, хоть каждые полсекунды, а раз в минуту отсылай запрос в БД.

**Кешировать запросы на INSERT ИМХО пагубное и неправильное дело!**

Определись для чего тебе нужен кеш! Я вот смотрю и вижу что он тут вообще не нужен. Тут нужно просто хранить кое какие данные в куках или сессии а раз в N-ное кол-во времени сливать на сервак, но опять же если это 10К запросов, то сервак будет постоянно забит запросами ежесекундно, а вот отсылать ему запросы реже - лучше, 
либо: Записывать нужные данные в сессии пользователей, потом их по 300-500 штук (пользователей) сваливать во временную таблицу, может и не одну для быстроты, ну а потом их мержить в главную таблицу, но уже по крону на стороне сервака, что убыстрит процесс.

Comment: «Отвалился пользователь» (ключевой момент!), и кто сессию-сироту в базу засунет, спрашивается? Или где тот очередной запрос, что раз-в-10-минут данные сравнит?

Кроме того, знаешь, где обычно сессии хранятся? Бывает, в файлах, а бывает, в той же БД. Оперативка memcached побыстрее будет.

Comment: «до следующего визита» — пользователя, на следующий день, в эту игру.

«какие .. варианты, если нужно постоянно хранить в БД» — данные эти нужны только самому же этому пользователю. Хранить их приходится на сервере. Обновляются во время игры раз в 1 сек. Поэтому нужен кэш. Бо FB и десятки тыс игрунов, чтоб им книжки читалось лучше.

«раз в минуту отсылай запрос в БД» — это **вариант** с толерантностью к потере данных за последнюю минуту. 90% решения. Хочется без потерь. Потому, что деньги. Юзеры покупают доп. баки.

Comment: А разве FB и VK не предоставляют переменные для хранения? у VK же есть пользовательские переменные в которые можно засунуть кучу данных, и их оттуда потом вытащить при разрыве клиента. **Это раз**

Ну а 2, можно для такого "неправильного решения" выделить хороший сервак, который будет выдерживать нагрузку такую и работать будет только с MySql сервером иметь несколько таблиц и только! 

Или это будет Кеширующий сервак, на который будет сливаться кеш запросов, ну а потом так же по крону писаться в оригинальную БД, но сервак должен быть мощный тогда, в этом тоже есть смысл.

Comment: Вообще оптимизация должна закладываться изначально, при разработке игры или сервиса.

Comment: "Это раз" мимо: владельцам игры также нужна иногда общая статистика по покупкам и растрате бомб. Выдёргивать по одному из переменных хранимых в FB никто не будет. С **2** вернёмся к вопросу: как по крону писать в БД из кэша. Весь кэш писать глупо. Видимо, надо писать в БД только записи, которые не дергали >T секунд. Пока они не исчезли из кэша из-за их TTL. Это всё мои домыслы. А, возможно, существует неизвестная ни вам, ни мне практика на подобные случаи.